# I cannot center text vertically

Tags: css, wordpress, text, vertical-alignment

[I cannot vertically center text as shown in this image. The site is based on WordPress. I do not know which class is responsible for this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoJbX.jpg)

http://dergax.ayz.pl/ 
[What causes the problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoJbX.jpg)

Comment: Your question is **extremely** unclear. If you expect any answers, please edit your question to explain EXACTLY what the problem is that you are looking to fix.

Comment: Sorry. I hope it's good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has long been the bane of CSS, but has now been fixed using "flex" boxes. On your site, you should add this CSS to the element with the classes  `et_pb_row.et_pb_row_0`:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Here's some further reading: https://www.adam-bray.com/2017/02/17/simple-css-alignments-with-flexbox/

Hope that helps

Comment: @PatrykKożuchowski In this case, you should click the checkmark next to his answer to accept it.

Comment: @PatrykKożuchowski glad to hear it. Please mark it as the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the text in the yellow box to the left of the image halfway down the site, try this by going to **APPEARANCE > CUSTOMIZE > ADDITIONAL CSS**

```
   .et_pb_row_0 p {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 200px;
}
```